# Java Pattern Regex for finding numbers not ending with specific substring

Tags: java, regex

I´m trying to capture a substring of a line in Java using the pattern and matcher logic. For the current application I need to remove a substring of a line. therefore i want to capture the whole substring ending with a number which should not end with a specified 3 digit number reserved for other purposes. I also can´t simply Strip of a hardcoded amount of characters from my line, therefore a regex is needed. To simplify the Problem, the regex should just capture numbers of 9 digits not ending with 770.

this should be the results:

```
233456770 --> NO HIT
454683870 --> HIT
459987579 --> HIT
```

i tried the solution with the following solution, Stripping all numbers ending with a 0

```
\d{6}[^9][^9][^0]
```

I also tried a lookbehind, which resulted either in the substring beeing too Long or to short since there are 3 digits missing or too much

`\d{6}(?!990)` and

```
\d{9}(?!990)
```

**So how to detect and capture a number not ending with a specified substring while keeping the whole detected number (withoud removing the last three digits checked) in the resulting substring using Java Pattern language?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\d)\d{9}(?!\d)(?<!770)
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/4jAoFZ/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `\d{9}` - nine digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately to the right of the current location is allowed
- `(?<!770)` - no `770` allowed immediately to the left of the current location.

Java string literal:

```
String regex = "(?<!\\d)\\d{9}(?!\\d)(?<!770)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid regexex if I can since they are hard to debug and have worse performance.

If you can use plain java:

```
num !=null && num.length() == 9 && num.length.endsWith("770")
```